# Received delayed response from HMHomeManagerDelegate:didRemoveHome for in app delete operation

Tags: ios, swift, ios-homekit

We are using the Homekit framework in our application and we are facing a strange issue.

As per the below Apple documentation HMHomeManagerDelegate protocol provide updates regarding home changes made outside the application.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhomemanager

In our case, we are receiving a delayed response from HMHomeManagerDelegate even though the home add/remove operation is performed from the same app and not from the outside. Please find below the steps.

1. Launch the app and delete 'ABC' Home
2. Log out from the app and close the app.
3. Relaunch and login to the app
4. Create the home 'ABC'
5. HMHomeManagerDelegate:didAddHome reports 'ABC' home created
6. HMHomeManagerDelegate:didRemoveHome reports 'ABC' home deleted. It is delete home response for step 1.